# Chatbot maintaining flow

Tags: node.js, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have developed a web Chatbot using socket.io/nodejs/LUIS. I'm not using bot builder. I'm new to models.

My flow will be like socket-> luis->Response function.
This flow can be used for single req and response.but it can't handle complex conversations like form inputs,prompt dialog.

How can I incorporate such complex conversations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are at the beginning of your journey with chatbots, I will propose you to take a look at [Teambot project](https://github.com/teambot-club/teambot). This is an open source project so you can give it a try, go through the code to get some ideas or contribute to it.